# Creating Firm Pairs

Tags: sas

I am trying to create firm pairs in my data in order to calculate distance.

My current data looks as follows:

```
Firm Zipcode      
A 15452

B 98565

C 62645  

D 12745

...
```

I would like to create a new data set that looks like this:

```
Focus Firm FocusZip FirmZip

A B 15452 98565

A C 15452 62645

A D 15452 12745

B C 98565 62645

B D 98565 12745

C D 62645 12745

...
```

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas how to code this in SAS?

Comment: Where does the FocusZip come from? What are the rules? What have you tried so far to solve the problem on your own? Please review the guidelines on how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: FocusZip is the zip code of the focus firm and FirmZip is the zip code of the matched firm. Firm A will get matched up with every firm in the sample that is not Firm A (in this case it is Firm B, C, D). Likewise, Firm B will be matched up with every firm in the sample that does not include Firm A (in this case Firm C, D). This is because the Firm A Firm B pair already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a SQL cross join and add a filter via a WHERE clause to exclude the ones that are the same.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select a.*, b.zipcode as focus_zip
from have as a, have as b
where a.firm ne b.firm and a.firm < b.firm;
quit;
```

Comment: Probably add `where a.firm <  b.firm` or similar,  to avoid the duplicate entries, no?